# Regex Nested quantifier +

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace `c++` with `<b>c++</b>` in the following string:

```
"Select the projects entry and then select VC++ directories. Select show"
```

I want it to be

```
"Select the projects entry and then select V<b>C++</b> directories. Select show"
```

Im using this code :

```
string cssOld = Regex.Replace(
   "Select the projects entry and then select VC++ directories. Select show",
   "c++", "<b>${0}</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I get the following error :
`System.ArgumentException: parsing "c++" - Nested quantifier +.`

This code works fine with other text(!c++). It seems like the + operator cause the Regex library to throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape special characters in `regex`:

```
string cssOld = Regex.Replace(
    "Select the projects entry and then select VC++ directories. Select show ",
    @"c\+\+", "${0}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Do i only have to cater for + operator or are there any other operators(*,&,\ etc) that can cause this exception as well?

Comment: You can check this for other special characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions . Among them are the following: (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space)

Comment: Oh thanks. Regex.Escape did do the job as well. So i changed my code to:

string cssOld = Regex.Replace(Regex.Escape("Select the projects entry and then select VC++ directories. Select show
"),Regex.Escape("c++"), "<b>${0}</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

And it works fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

`+` is a special character in regexes; it means "match one or more of the preceding character".

To match a literal `+` character, you need to escape it by writing `\+` (inside an `@""` literal)

To match arbitrary literal characters, use `Regex.Escape`.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Do i only have to cater for + operator or are there any other operators(*,&,\ etc) that can cause this exception as well?

Comment: Oh thanks. Regex.Escape did do the job as well. So i changed my code to:

string cssOld = Regex.Replace(Regex.Escape("Select the projects entry and then select VC++ directories. Select show
"),Regex.Escape("c++"), "<b>${0}</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

And it works fine. Thank you all.